# Function for getting one instance of each element in a vector in R

Tags: r

I would like to know which elements occur in a vector that has a lot of clones.  Please, before you suggest using `levels()`, let me explain first.

So, for example:

```
data <-c( "Jan", "Jan", "Feb", "Feb", "Feb", "Mar" )

supermagicfunction( data )
[1] "Jan" "Feb" "Mar"
```

As you see, I'm working with dates. I'm using POSIX (actually `strftime()`) for that. This is where the problem is. Normally, I would use levels. But that returns all months of the year as levels because I work with POSIX dates. Like this:

```
levels( data )
[1] "Jan" "Feb" "Mar" "Apr" "May" "Jun" "Jul" "Aug" "Sep" "Oct" "Nov" "Dec"
```

I assume POSIXct kindly determines the levels for this vector.

Now, my question is: Does anyone know a function (perhaps even a primitive?) that could help here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ha! I just found it myself. This will work:

```
unique( data )
[1] "Jan" "Feb" "Mar"
```

And it's fast, too.

Comment: Interesting... Didn't I just post it in comments?

Comment: Well, we both know it's unlikely but possible. I appreciate your input though. You know what? If you make it an answer, I will give you the upvote and mark it as solved. How is that?